# Why does the getPrototype method call result in an error?

Tags: javascript, prototype

If every object inherits eventually from the highest level Object and that highest level Object has the getPrototypeOf() function/method, why does the following code produce an error?

```
obj = {};
proto = obj.getPrototypeOf(obj);
```

Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'getPrototypeOf'

When I look in IE10's (F12 developer tools) Locals tab, it says obj has a prototype, and that prototype has methods, one of which is isPrototypeOf.

Here is my complete html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
obj = {};
proto = obj.getPrototypeOf(obj);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note: I'm specifically asking why it shows up as a method under the prototype for obj, yet produces an error (if it's suppose to only be a method of Object, but not the inherited prototype)?  I would post a screenshot of it, but my reputation is too low since I'm new.

Comment: Check the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getPrototypeOf

Comment: I did.  It doesn't help me with this question.  (or I'm not seeing it)

Comment: You said `isPrototypeOf`? Versus `getPrototypeOf`?

Comment: isPrototypeOf belongs to Object.prototype, so all objects inherit that method. getPrototypeOf belongs to the Object constructor object only.

Comment: Apologies!  I see it now.  I'm referencing getPrototypeOf, yet I'm seeing isPrototypeOf.  You were correct.  Thank you.

Comment: I flagged this question for the moderator to delete if they can, since it's a silly oversight on my part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getPrototypeOf` is on the `Object` object and not on instances of an object, try

```
obj = {};
proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
```

Comment: but then why does the method show up listed under the prototype for obj?

Comment: Where does this happen?

Comment: IE10 F12 developer screen under the Script tab, and then locals tab (when I expand the + sign for obj).

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getPrototypeOf` is not a method on all objects, it's a method on the... `Object` object. Use `Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
obj = {};
proto = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)
```